# Material Components for IOS : MDCBottomAppBarView

Tags: material-design

I have checked around but no able to find any info about this.

Is there any way to set text and image in MDCBottomAppBarView, among setting the high of MDCBottomAppBarView ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Image by `setImage`:

```
let appBarBottom = MDCBottomAppBarView()
appBarBottom.floatingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // Change this if you have another color icon
appBarBottom.floatingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "IMAGE NAME"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
```